# Why my mocked service property is undefined in Jasmine unit test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

Im learning Angular unit testing with Jasmine. I am following [documentation`s guide for testing services](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services), but for another service from the tutorial, also very simple.

SUT:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HeroService {

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    // TODO: send the message _after_ fetching the heroes
    this.messageService.add('HeroService: fetched heroes');
    return of(HEROES);
  }

  getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    // TODO: send the message _after_ fetching the hero
    this.messageService.add(`HeroService: fetched hero id=${id}`);
    return of(HEROES.find(hero => hero.id === id));
  }
}
```

And injected MessageService:

```
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MessageService {
  messages: string[] = [];

  add(message: string) {
    this.messages.push(message);
  }

  clear() {
    this.messages = [];
  }
}
```

As per guide, I mocked injected service using `createSpyObj` and called `getHeroes` of the SUT:

```
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

describe('HeroService without Angular testing support', () => {
  let heroService: HeroService;
  let messageServiceSpy: MessageService;

  it('#getHeroes should add message to MessageService', () => {
    //prepare
    messageServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj(
      'MessageService',
      ['add'],
      ['messages']
    );
    heroService = new HeroService(messageServiceSpy);
    messageServiceSpy.messages = ['one', 'two'];//only difference with the guide

    //act
    heroService.getHeroes();

    //assert
    expect(messageServiceSpy.messages.length).toBe(3);
    expect(messageServiceSpy.messages[2]).toBe('HeroService: fetched heroes');
  });
});
```

Because of some reason, when testing, `messageServiceSpy.messages` is `undefined`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

What Im doing wrong?

Comment: `Unit` tests should test the class that you `describe`, and everything else should be mocked. You're trying to test another services functionality inside of `HeroService`, which completely goes against that.

Comment: @MikeS. Actually it is a very good point. I was silly doing that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final (for Jasmine 3.6) **hero.service.spec.ts** file is:

```
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

describe('HeroService without Angular testing support', () => {
  let heroService: HeroService;
  let messageServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj(
    'MessageService',
    ['add'],
    ['clear']
  );
  heroService = new HeroService(messageServiceSpy);

  it('#getHeroes should call add() once with string value', () => {
    //prepare
    messageServiceSpy.add.calls.reset();

    //act
    heroService.getHeroes();

    //assert
    expect(messageServiceSpy.add).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(messageServiceSpy.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      'HeroService: fetched heroes'
    );
  });

  it('#getHero should call add() once with proper string value', () => {
    //prepare
    messageServiceSpy.add.calls.reset();
    let id = 1;

    //act
    heroService.getHero(id);

    //assert
    expect(messageServiceSpy.add).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(messageServiceSpy.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      'HeroService: fetched hero id=' + id
    );
  });
});
```

And version with Angular **TestBed** support:

```
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('HeroService with Angular testing support', () => {
  let heroService: HeroService;
  let messageServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<MessageService>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MessageService', ['add']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      // Provide both the service-to-test and its (spy) dependency
      providers: [HeroService, { provide: MessageService, useValue: spy }],
    });
    // Inject both the service-to-test and its (spy) dependency
    heroService = TestBed.inject(HeroService);
    messageServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(MessageService) as jasmine.SpyObj<
      MessageService
    >;
  });

  it('#getHeroes should call add() once with string value', () => {
    //prepare
    messageServiceSpy.add.calls.reset();

    //act
    heroService.getHeroes();

    //assert
    expect(messageServiceSpy.add).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(messageServiceSpy.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      'HeroService: fetched heroes'
    );
  });

  it('#getHero should call add() once with proper string value', () => {
    //prepare
    messageServiceSpy.add.calls.reset();
    let id = 1;

    //act
    heroService.getHero(id);

    //assert
    expect(messageServiceSpy.add).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(messageServiceSpy.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      'HeroService: fetched hero id=' + id
    );
  });
});
```

And approach WITHOUT **TestBed**:

```
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('HeroService with Angular testing support', () => {
  function setup() {
    const messageServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MessageService', ['add']);
    const heroService = new HeroService(messageServiceSpy);

    return { heroService, messageServiceSpy };
  }
  let heroService: HeroService;
  let messageServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<MessageService>;

  it('#getHeroes should call add() once with string value', () => {
    //prepare
    const { heroService, messageServiceSpy } = setup();

    //act
    heroService.getHeroes();

    //assert
    expect(messageServiceSpy.add).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(messageServiceSpy.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      'HeroService: fetched heroes'
    );
  });

  it('#getHero should call add() once with proper string value', () => {
    //prepare
    const { heroService, messageServiceSpy } = setup();
    let id = 1;

    //act
    heroService.getHero(id);

    //assert
    expect(messageServiceSpy.add).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(messageServiceSpy.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      'HeroService: fetched hero id=' + id
    );
  });
});
```